# How to change ssh agent unix socket location on server side

Tags: sshd

When I connect to the remote machine `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` gets set to `/tmp/ssh-RANDOM_HASH/agent.PID`. Is it possible to configure `sshd` to use different location for `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`.  I would like to use `/tmp/ssh/RANDOM_HASH/agent.PID` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dug a little in the code and found that path pattern ([auth_sock_dir](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/bef92346c4a808f33216e54d6f4948f9df2ad7c1/session.c#L200)) is hardcoded and [the function (auth_input_request_forwarding)](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/bef92346c4a808f33216e54d6f4948f9df2ad7c1/session.c#L186) is marked as static. So theres is no way to set a different pattern in config and there is
no way to preload a different function.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually `ssh-agent` that sets the `SSH_AUTH_SOCKET` environment variable.  You can use the `-a` option when you start `ssh-agent` to put the socket somewhere other than the default (and `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` will be set accordingly).  However, the pattern that is used to construct the socket name is hardcoded, and you won't be able to change the default location without modifying the `ssh-agent` source code.

Comment: What do you actually mean by that last sentence? The pathname given as an argument to the `-a` option will be used as the socket name, overriding the default location. You seem to say you _can_ override the default location, only to immediately say you can't.

Comment: You can override the default name using the `-a` option, and that filename will be propagated to the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable setting, but it is a fixed, static name - not a pattern (such as what you want, using `/tmp/ssh/RANDOM_HASH/agent.PID`.  So, you would have to script it such that the name you pass in with `-a` matches the pattern that you want.  If you leave it as the default (without using `-a`), then `ssh-agent` creates a pathname by itself, using a pattern that is hardcoded into the source code and can't be changed.

Comment: I don't think ssh-agent is running on remote machine when I connect to it. `lsof` on remote machine shows that socket belongs to `sshd`.